# Why does bundler resolve dependencies differently with locally unpacked gems versus downloaded ones?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler, gemfile

**Context:**

We have a packaging system (yum) that is used to install two packages (puppet and facter) onto our production systems. It installs facter 2.4.3 as a dependency (according to yum/RPM) of puppet 3.1.1 .

There's nothing wrong with the production puppet/facter packages, but I've been having trouble convincing Bundler to install that particular version combination in test environments.

According to the `puppet-3.1.1` *gem*, it facter versions greater than 2 are not allowed as dependences, which contradicts the facter version required by the `puppet-3.1.1` *rpm*. Also, certain tests/puppet behaviors fail in bundle/testing environments using the facter version that the puppet gem "wants".

**TL;DR: the one gem (puppet) has a Gemfile dependency that doesn't work in our testing case, and is explicitly violated in production, and I need to convince Bundler to install two theoretically-conflicting gems.**

**Problem:**

I tried the suggested solution for gem problems from the Bundler docs: forking the problematic gem in question and fixing the problems myself. That's where it started to get weird.

If I point Bundler at a *prstine* copy of the puppet-3.1.1 gem, Bundler will install whatever version of the dependency (facter) I want. However, if I point Bundler at that *same gem version on the internet*, dependency resolution fails.

Given this Gemfile:

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'puppet', '3.1.1'
gem 'facter', '2.4.3'
```

`bundle install` fails with:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........
Resolving dependencies...
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "facter":
  In Gemfile:
    puppet (= 3.1.1) ruby depends on
      facter (~> 1.6) ruby

    facter (2.4.3)
```

However, if I `gem fetch puppet -v 3.1.1` and `gem unpack [download location]` (no modifications are made to the gem contents), and update the Gemfile to say

```
source "https://rubygems.org"
gem 'puppet', '3.1.1', :path => "./download_location"
gem 'facter', '2.4.3'
```

...everything works.

**Question:**

I'm fine maintaining a local copy of the problematic gem, but I'd like to know: **why does bundler consider dependencies to be satisfied against an unmodified local copy of a gem, when those dependencies fail if it uses that same gem from the internet?**

As a follow-up/extra help, if anyone has ideas about how to more effectively manage issues like this (an OS package manager and Bundler having a mutually-exclusive disagreement about gem dependency versions) without having to maintain thousands of files in local forks, I'd love to hear them.

Comment: Why are you maintaining a gem locally? Why not use the gem from github or rubygems? Also, please condense your question to the least information needed to understand.

Comment: If I use the gem from rubygems, the problem I am asking about occurs. I can't use github, as they don't maintain tags far enough back for the version I want. 

I updated the question for brevity.

Comment: Can you post your Gemfile.lock when you said "everything works" case.

Comment: In the "everything works" case, the puppet gem shows up under the "PATH" section of my Gemfile.lock, rather than in the GEM section. There's also an exclamation point after it in the "DEPENDENCIES" section.